# Lock records when certain conditions are met

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm creating a database that registers working hours.
People can introduce start working day, when and how long they take lunch break, and the end of the working day.
All works well, and I've created some tables that proplery catch the time.

BUT my manager wants to prevent that people can change their working hours the next day (unless of course the field is empty because the user forgot). The user should only change his working hours when the admin (manager) gives access via a password.

Note that I've created a separate database for each user (which is automatically created when the user registers) due to the need for password protection.

How would I handle this best? I don't know if locking records would work (?).
Locking controls doesn't have a purpose, because the user obviously has manual access to his own personalized password protected database.

I could provide code, but the code I would provide would be useless to this specific problem... 
(I've got a hundreds of lines by now, all not really anything to do with this specific problem).

Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: It sounds as if Jet/Ace may not have been the best choice for a backend. How about forgetting about locking, create an mde and email the admin if any change is made to yesterday's data?

Comment: Probably true, but they hired me to do any job in VBA with Access/Excel (it is only a small company with about 8 employees in total) and there are no other developers for IT support (only network administrators). About the automatic email, that sounds like a good idea! I guess I won't even need the MDE... they use Outlook, so I can just send the email with information on the change. Thanks!

Comment: You need the mde to stop some smart alec messing with the code and stopping the email.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm going to look into that.

Comment: Switch over to SQL Server Express edition (It's FREE!!!).  You can keep your MS Access front end if you like, but the most important thing is you can actually enforce security, like the ability to do inserts only, but not do updates by allowing or disallowing the ability to execute certain stored procedures.  It's going to be a little more involved, but it's really the best way to go.  There is a ton of support on this site on how to do a VBA application linked to a SQL Server backend.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm going to look into that...!

Comment: I'm on holidays for a week now, but it looks promising. If it is the best solution, I will definitely go go for that. However, since my main task is to create an insurance accounting system and I have a deadline before end 2013, I hope that the conversion to sql server express will be pretty smooth and that the vba will work smoothly too. But according to TexasTubbs, it doesn't appear to be a problem.

Comment: I have to mention that at the moment I allowed changes in the past, but the admin is notified when this happens if it's more than 1 day in the past. In exceptional situations I became aware that the update should still be allowed.